# Javascript method new Date()

Tags: javascript, date

In case I have following:

```
var day = '29';
var month = '12';
var year = '2015';

var created_date = new Date(year, month, year); // first
var created_date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), parseInt(year)); // second
```

Can I create new date as it described in "**first**" line? Or do I need to parse integer out of string first as it shown in "**second**" line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And the month is 0 indexed, for December you need `var month = 11`;

Comment: Guys I do misspelled year twice and forgot that months in JavaScript start counting from 0.

I just wanted to know, does it require casting or I can simply use strings as numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Date("2015", "11", "23") // This work perfect, but it should be yy, mm, dd and not yy, mm, yy
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a both way except you have to `-1` to the month

```
var day = '29';
var month = '12';
var year = '2015';
var created_date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
```

This will work correctly.

You know, you have entered `year` to the `day` parameter of `Date()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var day = '29';
var month = '12';
var year = '2015';
var month1=parseInt(month)-1;
var created_date = new Date(year, month1.toString(), day); 
console.log(created_date);
var created_date1 = new Date(parseInt(year), month1, parseInt(day));
console.log(created_date1);
```

both statements are correct in order to obtain new date but the format inside the new Date(); should be of type yy,mm,dd not in yy,mm,yy

Comment: Months are 0-indexed, so month 12 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of date are:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

The only caveat to keep in mind is that January is month 0.
So if a user inputs 12 for December, or 10 for October, substract one.

Another caveat to remember is that dates may unexpectedly shift. 
Doing `new Date(2012,1,31)` will result in 31 march instead of 31 February(because it only has 28/29 days). So always do some sanity checking.

As to your second question:

Javascript is type unsafe.

`"22"` is the same as `22` when fed into the Date object.
`1 == true`, `0 == false`, `"1" == 1 == true` etc..  There are some caveats here and there. But usually it's not neccesary to typecast variables.

`1 + true` = `2`
 "22"/4+0.5 = 6

And so on. Only in cases when javascript clearly can't hack(for example addition of string numbers `"22"+1` = `"221"`) it should you do explicit typecasting. Or when you need something to be a number. This is in cases where a string starts with a number, but doesn't only contain numeric characters. Like `"22"` will be treated a s a number, but `"22foo"` will be a string. You need to explicitly cast that to an integer to get the number. `parseInt('22foo')` will result in a `22`.

Doing sanity testing on user input is always a good practise. Is the variable  what I expect it to be. With integers, if the user has a chance to feed in other characters it's wise to use the isNaN function to test.

You can use the is Not A Number function of javascript to test if a string is pure. `isNaN('22')` will return `false` because the answer on the question "is it not a number" is negative. `isNaN('22foo')` will return `true`. A little bit of around the twist logic. I find it useful to remember this particular function as a question to keep my sanity :-)

Like `"22foo" + 2` will turn into `"22foo2"`. so a `parseInt("22foo")+2` would result the desired `24` output.

Comment: '*Javascript is type insentive*" is not true. In some cases, it performs type conversion (in this case, strings are converted to numbers if they can be) but not always (e.g. `new Date(value)` will not type convert *value* if it is a string).

Comment: `new Date('2012',true,20)` simply turns into `'Mon Feb 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)'` So what do you mean? if you mean a string like `2012xx` that would fail, but for that is my last sentence in my answer

Comment: `"22" is the same as 22` is just plain wrong. `"22" === 22` returns `false`. `typeof "22"` returns `string`, and `typeof 22` returns `number`. Downvoted for this.

Comment: Do you see me use 3 equal operators? *NO*. == wil return true. You use === to test for same type.  That is beyond the scope of the answer. Javascript IS type insentive. It's just wonky about when it is and when not `"22" + 1` will become "221" but `"22"/4 = 5.5`. It's a very unstable language concerning when and where a variable will remain it's own type or what it will accept.

Comment: I modified one word in my answer to fit your purist interpretation of words.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it brought more sense now!

Comment: @MichaelDibbets—I mean what I said: ECMAScript absolutely cares about Types. For example, if a single argument is passed to the *Date* constructor then it will be treated differently depending on its Type, and `new Date(22)` returns an entirely different result to `new Date("22")`. It is impossible to "typecast variables" since they don't have a type, values do.